# Problems with new version of Android Studio (Not seeing ConstraintLayoutand and other views, some activities in the manifest ...)

Tags: android, android-studio, view, manifest, android-constraintlayout

[image]why is it happening? don't understand: why? How can it be?

[image: why is it happening?]

But in the other fragment everything is OK

one more:
[image]

and in android manifest
[image: not seeing activities]

Comment: but in neighboring layout everything is OK

Comment: created a bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157981135

Comment: solved with studio 4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved with studio 4.1, downloaded it and installed